# Can't see item_id in select_content on Firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, events, firebase-analytics

I've set up Firebase in my project, using this script to log events:

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.EventSelectContent, new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter(Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.ParameterItemId, "MY_ITEM"));
```

When I run the app on a device, I can see my events using the Realtime panel of my Firebase Dashboard. This shows me select_content which I can then drill down into to to see the item_id and the name I have given it.

When I go into the Events panel however, it shows the select_content parameter, but I can't see any further information than that; no item_id or the name I've given it.

There must be a way to show this information, does anyone know how to access it?

Comment: I've noticed the same thing, only showing three of the content types and not showing item_id's at all. The same for all the other event types, mainly missing info. It seems you can only get those values for the last 30 minutes, and that by digging through the realtime panel.